# Angular: access variable which is declared inside subscribe function

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm trying to access a variable inside a subscribe function but it returns to me undefined, please any suggestions:

```
export class InboxmanagementComponent implements OnInit {

       releveBancaireId: number;


   ngOnInit(): void {

      this.displayTaskByIdDetails();
      this.displayReleveBancaireById();
   }

   displayTaskByIdDetails(){
      this._inboxServcie.getTask(this.task.id).subscribe(
           (data) => {
              this.task = data;
              this.releveBancaireId = data.releveBancaireId;  // this is the variable I want to access
           console.log(this.releveBancaireId) // this returs 1 which is right "releveBancaireId" has value 1
          }
      );
    }

    displayReleveBancaireById(){

      this._relebeBancaireService.getReleveBancaireById(this.releveBancaireId).subscribe( // this is where I want to access that variable as a parameter
          (data) => {
              this.releveBancaire = data;
              console.log(data);
          }
      );
    }

}
```

this.task inside displayTaskByIdDetails function returns this:

[image]

Meaning that I have to use that property `releveBancaireId` which is returned from `displayTaskByIdDetails` and use it in another function which calls a service as a parameter

This is my service which needs releveBancaireId as a parameter:

```
 getReleveBancaireById(id: number): Observable<ReleveBancaire>{
        const taskIdUrl = `${this.baseUrl}/${id}`;
        return this.httpClient.get<any>(taskIdUrl).pipe(
            map((response: any) => response)
        );
    }
```

When compiling console returns `undefined`

[image]

Comment: do you request both same time?

Comment: No not the same time, but `displayTaskByIdDetails` should be loaded at first and then the `data` has a property ` data.releveBancaireId; ` which I want to use it

Comment: can you share the code where you execute the 2 functions just we can get an idea if this is an execution order issue. This might be solved with a simple pipe

Comment: I have updated my question Lavstsen. Thanks

Comment: I dont have much experience on angular but is there a way to reuse subscribe of `displayTaskByIdDetails` inside `displayReleveBancaireById` and get that value from it ?

Answer (score 1):

Ok so since the calls are sequential its a perfect opotunity to use mergeMap to chain multple requests. since you still need the data from the first request you can tap that data and retrive it. and on the final subscribe you will get the data from the final request.

```
export class InboxmanagementComponent implements OnInit {

 releveBancaireId: string;


 ngOnInit(): void {
    this.displayTaskByIdDetails();
 }

  displayTaskByIdDetails(){
    this._inboxServcie.getTask(this.task.id).pipe(
        tap(taskData=>{
            this.task = taskData
            this.releveBancaireId = taskData.releveBancaireId;  // incase you still need this.
        }),
        mergeMap(data=>{
             return  this._relebeBancaireService.getReleveBancaireById(data.releveBancaireId);
        })).subscribe((data) => {
          this.releveBancaire = data;
          console.log(data);
        });
  }
}
```

Comment: still undefined, I added a photo at the end of my question

Comment: probably a small thing but the releveBancaireId is not a number from the api Its a string. Dont think that is the issue though can you console log the data inside the mergeMap to see if releveBancaireId  is undefined there ?

Comment: surely not about that I've changed it to number and still the same, but I just to take that value and use it inside `displayReleveBancaireById` to reach what I want because this function will have alot of implementations